# sonata user management check box is missing from role

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

my check box is missing from addnew user /management tab, when i was trying to create a new user in sonata user (means i can't access any role for assigning it to any user or for creating a role group

here is my 
**config.yml**:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration


# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~


# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }
bc_bootstrap:
    less_filter: less
    assets_dir:  %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap
    jquery_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/jquery/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)

sonata_admin:
    title:      Admin
    #title_logo: bundles/acmedemo/img/fancy_acme_logo.png
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
        #acl_user_manager: fos_user.user_manager
                    # Name of the user manager service used to retrieve ACL users

    options:
        html5_validate: false
                    # does not use html5 validation
        confirm_exit:   false
                    # disable confirmation when quitting with unsaved changes

    # set to true to persist filter settings per admin module in the user's session
    #persist_filters: false
    templates:
        dashboard: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig
        search:              SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig
        search_result_block: SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_search_result.html.twig
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            -
                position: left
                type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list
            -
                position: right
                type: sonata.block.service.text
                settings:
                    content: >
                        <h2>Welcome Admin</h2>

sonata_user:
    security_acl: false
    manager_type: orm
            # can be orm or mongodb
    table:
        user_group: "my_custom_user_group_association_table_name"

    #impersonating:
    #    route:                page_slug
    #    parameters:           { path: / }

    class:                  # Entity Classes
        user:               Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:              Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

    admin:                  # Admin Classes
        user:
            class:          Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\UserAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation:    SonataUserBundle

        group:
            class:          Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\GroupAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation:    SonataUserBundle

    profile:

        menu:
            - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_show', label: 'sonata_profile_title', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}
            - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_edit', label: 'link_edit_profile', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}
            #- { route: 'sonata_customer_addresses', label: 'link_list_addresses', domain: 'SonataCustomerBundle'}
            - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_edit_authentication', label: 'link_edit_authentication', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}
            #- { route: 'sonata_order_index', label: 'order_list', domain: 'SonataOrderBundle'}
        # This allows you to specify where you want your user redirected once he activated his account

        form:
            type:               sonata_user_profile
            handler:            sonata.user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               sonata_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile]

    google_authenticator:
        enabled: true
        server:  yourserver.com

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
            # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User

    group:
        group_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
    profile:
        # Authentication Form
        form:
            type:               fos_user_profile
            handler:            fos_user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Authentication]
                    # Please note : this is not the default value
```

And here is my **security.yml**:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_USER: ROLE_MY_CUSTOM

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false


        main:
            pattern:             ^/
            context:             user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true

        admin:
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
            anonymous:          true

    acl:
        connection: default

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/demo/secured/hello/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    access_decision_manager:
        # Strategy can be: affirmative, unanimous or consensus
        strategy: unanimous
```

And here is my **routing.yml**:

```
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connected user must have the ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN role

do a

```
php app/console fos:user:promote [username] ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
```

and make sure to call this in your UserAdmin

```
->add('realRoles', 'sonata_security_roles', array(
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'required' => false
))
```

Comment: its showing this {User "admin" did already have "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN" role.}

Comment: you can't access to any roles, even sonata auto-generated ones ?

Comment: you don't override the roles attribute in protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) ?

Comment: can you just elaborate actually i didn't get what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

For symfony 4, use this:

```
use Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\SecurityRolesType;

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper): void
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('roles', SecurityRolesType::class, [
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ]);
}
```